# Django wsgi server bjoern multithreaded

Tags: django, multithreading, wsgi

i would like to use bjoern wsgi server, currently this is working fine but i want to get it multithreaded so that i can access my application localy on multiple ports not only on port 8080 but also und 8081, 8082 etc...

currently i do the following at my run.py file which starts the django app:

```
import bjoern

from app.wsgi import application

    bjoern.run(application, 'localhost', 8080, reuse_port=True)
```

how can i spawn multiple processes of run.py on diffrent ports?
Or in general how can i use multithreading at this point?
The documentation seems quite complicated to me or at least i dont know where to start, https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make multiple files with different ports?

Comment: Well this would be damn dirty i guess, beside i this would invoke my start cmd at my docker-compose file if i would do it like this.

Comment: Since bjoern is single-threaded, you're looking to emulate multithreadedness with this? Sounds like a bad idea. Maybe look into uwsgi, gunicorn or another natively multithreaded/multiprocess-supporting server instead.

Comment: Why bad? Seems to me like a performance boost

Comment: you should create couple of different processes (e.g managed with supervisor) and pass port via env variable or via command line parameter.